# Is there a way to access files on my Windows partition like an external drive or USB?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, files

I've put way more space into Windows than Ubuntu, because I was sure I was going to use Windows way more. But now I'm starting to become short on space.

Any ways to store and then PLAY movies,music etc. from my Windows partition?

Comment: Yes, you can play movies/music from your Windows partition, but there are some adjustments that need to be made from Windows, and this wouldn't be the best long term solution anyway. Best to resize your Windows and Ubuntu disk partitions. There's also a way to set it up so you can play music from both OS's without causing problems. If you edit your question and include a current-window-only screenshot of `gparted` I can make some recommendations and steps to perform. Start comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Answer (score 0):

You should see your Windows partition from the file manager, and you should be able to access it. However, you can use Gparted to resize your partitions. See here:

http://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dmoving-space-between-partitions

Comment: Will resizing with Gparted not corrupt/ruin my Windows image?

Comment: It shouldn't. See the guide I linked for further details. I think is your best choice.